# Can anyone help to identify this component? I couldn't find any info

Tags: components, surface-mount

[image][image: This is the image of the component and I couldn't find any info on the web with the]

This is the image of the component and I couldn't find any info on the web with these numbers.

[image]

Comment: What does the circuit it's in do?  Can you show us a picture of the components surrounding it (preferably the whole PCB) as well as the backside?

Comment: Zoomed in like that, it's rather impossible to determine even an enlightened guess what it might do in a circuit. It could be a 4-pin rectifier, 4-pin CM choke or transformer, or the 4 pins are really just two terminals of a 2 terminal component like an inductor. What is surrounding this component and is it  near power entry or power supply sections or somewhere else?

Comment: OK, given the second picture, they havea designator of T and are part of some power supply board, they might be transformers rather than inductors or CM chokes, if that helps.

Comment: @vir I took another photo of surroundings I can't send the whole PCB and that black heatsink has 4 transistor behind and I took photo from that too

Comment: In that case they might be pulse transformers for isolating the drive circuit from the transistors. You need to provide the schematis or reverse engineer them to narrow down what these are.

Comment: @Justme What i can see is that two out of three have swollen on top and the 3rd one is flat on top does that help to know what they are?

Comment: @Angelina Looks like you could easily (with an appropriate dental tool) lift the square lid on top of one. I'd waste no time and just do it and look inside. Taking the top off won't hurt anything. If you don't have, and need, dental tools then just ask your dentist. Last time I did that he ran back into an aisle and came back quickly giving me a huge handful of them. No cost. No fuss. But an exacto knife or box cutter would work as well. Just be careful with them.

Comment: @Angelina No, it does not help, because they are not capacitors and transformers do not get swollen up. And, Vishay does make custom pulse transformers, so there is a chance that they really are custom made Vishay pulse transformers so there will be no available info about them.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess they are gate drive transformers.  Vishay do a range of such [magnetics](https://origin-www.vishay.com/en/inductors/transformers/), and whilst I can't find an exact match, it seems a plausible fit with the other surrounding components, and the T designator.